# Security without TLS certificates

Tags: openssl, key-management, key-generation, key-exchange

after getting an answer to [Security over multi-streaming such as SCTP](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/90740/security-over-multi-streaming-such-as-sctp) i have found that i do *not* have the capacity to give a public key or certificate to the other end securely (to be sure MitM cannot substitute one and that no-one can see it).   i do have the capacity to send a 256-bit key securely.  both ends are under the same admin but there is no opportunity to set up a key or cert on either end besides the mentioned limited capacity (because it is a cloud image launched when needed).  "shared secret" seems to be the wrong terminology as all uses i see for this refer to sharing between different parties (the "sharing" is just between these two ends).  this is also a symmetric connection once established ... such as a VPN (it will be used as a VPN and it will use SCTP). my question is: how can i be sure this is secure?  security is hard.

i have used openssl before in [this script](https://skaperen.s3.amazonaws.com/tarnet) and am looking to use its C-layer API for this project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a variation of TLS that uses a Pre-Shared Key instead of certificates, called TLS-PSK. This basically works the same way as usual TLS except the session key is generated in a different way. You should take a look at this.

Comment: ok ... i will start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS-PSK

Comment: You may want to have a look at RFC 4279 too

Comment: that RFC is linked in the wiki article. i will look there next and then the openssl docs.